# Закрытие потока

Tags: java, потоки-данных, scanner

Здравствуйте, возник вопрос: например создал поток

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

я напишу в коде после этого **sc.close();**, чтобы он не использовал ресурсы. В таком случае при необходимости я могу после этого создать поток с этим же именем, после закрытия ведь он удаляеться?
Например, такой код:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc;
    int n;
    System.out.print("Введіть кількість квадратів: ");
        while (true) {
            sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            if (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.print("Некоректний тип введеного числа! Повторіть спробу: ");
            } else { 
                n = sc.nextInt();
                sc.close();
                break;
            }
        }
    Quadrate[] quadrates = new Quadrate[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < quadrates.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("Введіть сторону %d + 1 - го: ", i);
        double v = sc.doubleNextInt(); 
        quadrates[i] = new Quadrate(v);

    }   
}
}
```

Как правильно реализовать этот код?

Comment: Нет нужды на каждом проходе цикла создавать новый Scanner. Создайте один перед циклом.

Comment: помогите. пожалуйста, очень нужно

Comment: @Nofate,то есть каждое значение sc будет просто заменяться новым?

Comment: Нет. Будет просто одно значение sc.

Comment: @Nofate, вот весь код, прошу прощения, что сразу не скинул весь

Comment: ошибка была в написании метода (правильном написании)

Comment: надо sc.nextDouble();

Comment: конкретно в этом случае лучше вообще не закрывать, поскольку `scanner.close()` закроет заодно и `System.in`, после чего новые сканеры больше не смогут оттуда ничего прочитать. Ну и пересоздавать сканер, действительно, каждый раз не надо, достаточно одного экземпляра в начале метода.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вынесите создание `Scanner` в начало программы и используйте один экземпляр. Вызывать `sc.close();` в вашем случае нет никакой необходимости, т.к. это приведет к закрытию входного потока, из которого вы читаете.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        System.out.print("Введіть кількість квадратів: ");
        while (true) {
            if (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.print("Некоректний тип введеного числа! Повторіть спробу: ");
                sc.next()
            } else {
                n = sc.nextInt();
                break;
            }
        }
        Quadrate[] quadrates = new Quadrate[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < quadrates.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Введіть сторону %d + 1 - го: ", i);
            double v = sc.nextDouble();
            quadrates[i] = new Quadrate(v);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: понял спасибо, но есть новая проблема: кроме целых чисел не можна вводить вещественнуюсторону

Comment: @MuscledBoy, не уверен, что понял, в чем проблема.

Comment: для начала спрошу Вас,что делает внесенная Вами попровка. Мы проверяем целое ли число введено, если нет, то пишем, "Некоррекный ..." и что делаем тут?

Comment: возвращаем следующий токен?

Comment: а что такое токен вообще?

Comment: не совсем понимаю

Comment: А проблема все еще есть: когда в консоли вводишь сторону int - все нормально, double (2.4, например) - ошибка

Comment: я понимаю,что уже достал,но ведь для вопросов и создаются форумы

Comment: Помогите, пожалуйста